# Running the react native project pulled from github

Tags: javascript, react-native

I get an error when I want to run the project that I pulled from github and wanted to run.I've been coding for 1 week yet and I don't understand how to fix this, I would appreciate if you help me

All the steps and the errors I encountered are in the photos below.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Referans/src/Navigation/Login/Login.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: when i pressed run IOS]
[image: When i select react native selection]
[image: when i select run IOS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to run via terminal, `cmd+j` for terminal then

```
npm install
npx react-native run-android or npx react-native run-ios
```